# Requests to express-graphql fails with "message": "Authentication failed." after server is deployed to Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

I think it has something to do with Headers but I am not quite sure.
Running the NodeJs application locally doesn't have any problem and requests behave as usual.

My NodeJs staring point looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');

const schema = require('./graphql/schema');

const { PORT, listenCallback } = require('./config/server.config');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
    schema,
    graphiql: true,
}));

app.listen(PORT, listenCallback);
```

The response from the server always looks like this:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Authentication failed.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "profile"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "profile": null
  }
}
```

Is there something additionally that I should set in my configuration?
This happens only after server is successfully uploaded to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was having problems connecting to MongoDB in Heroku and it has nothing to GraphQl as previously thought.